# input date ranges in both array ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input

I have been working with this code:

```
var rangesInputRange1 = [
    { startDate: parseDate("15/04/2024"), endDate: parseDate("01/05/2024") },
    { startDate: parseDate("01/06/2024"), endDate: parseDate("30/06/2024") }
];

var rangesInputRange2 = [
    { startDate: parseDate("01/04/2024"), endDate: parseDate("14/04/2024") },
    { startDate: parseDate("01/07/2024"), endDate: parseDate("31/08/2024") }
];

function parseDate(dateString) {
    var parts = dateString.split("/");
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}

function isDateInRanges(date, ranges) {
  return ranges.some(function(range) {
    return date >= range.startDate && date <= range.endDate;
  });
}

function countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate) {
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  return Math.round(Math.abs((startDate - endDate) / oneDay));
}

jQuery('#start-date, #end-date').on('change', function() {
  var startDate = parseDate(jQuery('#start-date').val());
  var endDate = parseDate(jQuery('#end-date').val());

  var daysInRange1 = isDateInRanges(startDate, rangesInputRange1) ? countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate) : 0;
  var daysInRange2 = isDateInRanges(startDate, rangesInputRange2) ? countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate) : 0;

  var inputRange1 = jQuery('input.checkbox1');
  var inputNumber1 = jQuery('input.number1');
  var inputRange2 = jQuery('input.checkbox2');
  var inputNumber2 = jQuery('input.number2');

  inputRange1.prop('checked', daysInRange1 > 0).trigger('change');
  inputNumber1.val(daysInRange1).trigger('change');
  inputRange2.prop('checked', daysInRange2 > 0).trigger('change');
  inputNumber2.val(daysInRange2).trigger('change');
});

jQuery('#start-date, #end-date').trigger('change');
```

I have succeeded in if #start-date and #end-date are in same rangesInputRange. in this case, the code works fine.

How can I calculate daysInRange if the selected dates are in both rangesInputRange? (example: dates 10/04/2024 to 17/04/2024)

or selected dates are in  part in only one rangesInputRange? (example: 28/08/2024 to 03/09/2024).

(date format: dd/mm/YYYY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution that will work with any number of date `ranges`. The function `calc()` calculates the array `days` that contains the number of days for each range that is touched by the time period entered by the user. For now it is simply printed to the console.

```js
function advD(d){ // advance a date object by one day
 d.setDate(d.getDate()+1); return d;}
const ranges = [[ // using a slightly more standard way of predefining the date range dates
{ startDate: new Date(2024,3,15), endDate: new Date(2024,4,1) },
{ startDate: new Date(2024,5,1), endDate: new Date(2024,5,30) }
     ], [
{ startDate: new Date(2024,3,1), endDate: new Date(2024,3,14) },
{ startDate: new Date(2024,6,1), endDate: new Date(2024,7,31) }
]];

const inps=[...document.querySelectorAll("[type=date]")];
inps.forEach(inp=>inp.addEventListener("change",calc));

function calc(){
 const [ustart,uend]=inps.map(d=>new Date(d.value));
 advD(uend);
 const days=ranges.map(r=>Math.round(r.reduce((a,c)=>
  a+Math.max(Math.min(c.endDate,uend)-Math.max(c.startDate,ustart),0)  
 ,0)/86400000)); // turn milliseconds into days for each range
 console.log(days);
}

ranges.flat().forEach(d=>advD(d.endDate));
// calculate values for initial state of inputs:
calc();
```

```html
<input type="date" name="start" value="2024-03-27">
<input type="date" name="end" value="2024-05-07">
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for `countDaysInRange` function

```
function countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate) {
  var daysInRange1 = isDateInRanges(startDate, rangesInputRange1) ? Math.min(countDays(startDate, endDate, rangesInputRange1), 0) : 0;
  var daysInRange2 = isDateInRanges(startDate, rangesInputRange2) ? Math.min(countDays(startDate, endDate, rangesInputRange2), 0) : 0;

  return daysInRange1 + daysInRange2;
}

function countDays(startDate, endDate, ranges) {
  return ranges.reduce(function (totalDays, range) {
    var overlapStartDate = startDate < range.endDate ? startDate : range.startDate;
    var overlapEndDate = endDate < range.endDate ? endDate : range.endDate;

    if (overlapStartDate <= overlapEndDate) {
      return totalDays + Math.round((overlapEndDate - overlapStartDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }
    return totalDays;
  }, 0);
}
```

The `countDaysInRange` function now calculates the number of days in both ranges separately and returns the total number of days calculated for overlapping  or in-range periods.

**Update**

**Updated Code**

I hope this will help.

```
jQuery('#start-date, #end-date').on('change', function() {
  var startDate = parseDate(jQuery('#start-date').val());
  var endDate = parseDate(jQuery('#end-date').val());

  var daysInRange1 = isDateInRanges(startDate, rangesInputRange1) ? countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate, rangesInputRange1) : 0;
  var daysInRange2 = isDateInRanges(startDate, rangesInputRange2) ? countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate, rangesInputRange2) : 0;

  var inputNumber1 = jQuery('input.number1');
  var inputNumber2 = jQuery('input.number2');

  inputNumber1.val(daysInRange1).trigger('change');
  inputNumber2.val(daysInRange2).trigger('change');
});

// Separate countDaysInRange for each range
function countDaysInRange(startDate, endDate, ranges) {
  return ranges.reduce(function(totalDays, range) {
    var overlapStartDate = startDate < range.endDate ? startDate : range.startDate;
    var overlapEndDate = endDate < range.endDate ? endDate : range.endDate;

    if (overlapStartDate <= overlapEndDate) {
      return totalDays + Math.round((overlapEndDate - overlapStartDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }
    return totalDays;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but daysInRange1 and daysInRange2 must be separated to put values in inputNumber1 and inputNumber2.